# Model Validation Not Functioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm super frustrated by this one, because I've got to be doing something obviously wrong - but I can't seem to figure out what!

Basically, I'm trying to add validation to a model. When I test the validation in the console, none of the validators I've set up seem to work!

Here's the model in question:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :product, :presence => true
    validates :variant, :presence => true
    validates :price, :presence => true
    validates :start, :presence => true
    validates :end, :presence => true

    belongs_to :shop
end
```

Here's my console output:

```
1.9.2-p290 :008 > s = Sale.new
 => #<Sale id: nil, product: nil, variant: nil, start: nil, end: nil, price: nil, shop_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, compare_at: nil> 
1.9.2-p290 :009 > s.valid?
 => true 
1.9.2-p290 :010 > s.save
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "sales" ("compare_at", "created_at", "end", "price", "product", "shop_id", "start", "updated_at", "variant") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["compare_at", nil], ["created_at", Fri, 27 Jan 2012 02:06:40 UTC +00:00], ["end", nil], ["price", nil], ["product", nil], ["shop_id", nil], ["start", nil], ["updated_at", Fri, 27 Jan 2012 02:06:40 UTC +00:00], ["variant", nil]]
 => true
```

Now, if I understand [this article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validations-overview) correctly, `valid?` should return `false` because several of the object's attributes are nil, when the model defines that they shouldn't be - but it's not!

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the rails version you're using? Also, could you add in the Shop model source code? I just tested this out and it worked as expected.

Comment: `class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base end` -- and 3.1.3

Comment: And these are the only two models in the system? Also, you still haven't added the rails version.

Comment: Yes, those are the only two models in the system - aside from any that Delayed_Job adds for its purposes. I'm using Rails 3.1.3

Comment: Try `reload!` in the console or just restart it. There is also an option that you didn't saved `sale.rb` after adding the validations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error here was right in my face.

I had an addition file named Sale.rb, in a folder called jobs. This file re-opened the Sale class and added additional functionality relating to the `Delayed_Job` module. For an undetermined reason, this prevented the model validations from working or responding to methods like `valid?`. To resolve this, I simply added the methods I had written in this separate file, and concatenated them into model\Sale.rb.